# How to convert JSON values that START with a NUMBER to C# Class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

I use a web service whose output fields starts with a number like the below

```
[{"1_sell_count":"1","2_sell_count":"2","3_sell_count":"2"}]
```

Since I can't have a variable in C # that starts with a number and If I change the property name, the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method cannot do the conversion JSON To my Class.

how can I convert this JSON output to a C# class?

```
    List<myclass> reservationList = new List<myclass>();
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlApi))
                    {
                        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        reservationList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myclass>>(apiResponse);
                    }
```

and myclass.cs

```
 public class myclass
    {
        public string 1_sell_count{ get; set; }  //Not Valid Name
        public string 2_sell_count{ get; set; }   //Not Valid Name
        public string 3_sell_count{ get; set; }    //Not Valid Name
    }
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Use `JsonProperty(Name = <<You name here>>)` attribute over property.

Comment: Use `JsonProperty` or deserialize it to dictionary and parse manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute over property as shown below which instructs the `JsonSerializer` to always serialize the member with the specified name

```
public class myclass
{
    [JsonProperty("1_sell_count")]

    public string First_sell_count{ get; set; }  
    [JsonProperty("2_sell_count")]
    public string Second_sell_count{ get; set; }   
    
    [JsonProperty("3_sell_count")]
    public string Third_sell_count{ get; set; }    
}
```

See the fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/xGhtxv

With above your conversion logic would remain intact i.e.

```
reservationList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myclass>>(apiResponse);
```

However, you should be using the property name defined in the class to access the property in C# code.

Comment: Tanks graete, it worked @user1672994